# How can I make a databound control refresh a property value that was changed by reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, reflection

I bind a property to a textbox control (Windows form program), using the following code:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myObject, myPropertyName, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Further along in the program, I update the value of the property by reflection - using this code.

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(myPropertyName);
propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, myNewValue, null);
```

The property's value **is** being updated in the object.  I can see it in the debugger, when the code returns to the form.  However, the textbox does not show the new value.

If I clear the databinding on the textbox, and re-add it, it does show the new value.

How can I get the databound textbox to automatically display the new value, after setting the property value by reflection?

Comment: Do you implement NotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the binding work if you set it not using reflection? If it is still not working then you probably need to have your object implement INotifyPropertyChanged and then in your setter you need to raise the OnPropertyChanged event. This is how it works in WPF, I presume windows forms is the same or similar. Basically the binding needs a way to know that the property has changed, it does so by handling that event.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  My (incorrect) assumption was that binding would be a bit smarter and handle that internally.  After manually raising an OnPropertyChanged event, it works.

Comment: @ScottLilly I think if it was possible they would but there isn't really any way to do it except polling (which would be crap). The other thing is that sometimes the property might change as the result of another property changing or for any other reason besides it actually being set.